# Writing members from struct passed to function gives unexpected result

Tags: c, struct, io

First things first - my header (.h) file looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct riff_list {
    char id[4];
    uint32_t cksize;
    char subid[4];
    uint8_t *buf;
} list_t;

void write_u32_le(uint32_t n, FILE *f)
{
    uint8_t i, buf[4];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        buf[i] = n & 0xFF;
        n >>= 8;
    }

    fwrite(buf, 1, 4, f);
}

void init_list_chunk(list_t list, char *cktype)
{
    memcpy(list.id, "LIST", 4);
    list.cksize = 0;
    memcpy(list.subid, cktype, 4);
}

void write_list_chunk(list_t list, FILE *f)
{
    fwrite(list.id, 1, 4, f);
    write_u32_le(4 + list.cksize, f);
    fwrite(list.subid, 1, 4, f);
    fwrite(list.buf, 1, list.cksize, f);
}
```

Now, the problem is with a basic test program trying to write something to a file. This comes out as expected:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    list_t list;

    memcpy(list.id, "LIST", 4);
    list.cksize = 0;
    memcpy(list.subid, "TEST", 4);

    f = fopen("C:\\listtest.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(list.id, 1, 4, f);
    write_u32_le(4+list.cksize, f);
    fwrite(list.subid, 1, 4, f);
    list.buf = malloc(4);
    fwrite(list.buf, 1, 4, f);

    free(list.buf);
    fclose(f);
}
```

While this just produces a 4096-byte file with junk, with no recognizable parts of what is expected (not even "LIST"):

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    list_t list;

    init_list_chunk(list, "TEST");
    list.buf = malloc(4);
    list.cksize += 4;

    f = fopen("C:\\listtest.bin", "wb");
    write_list_chunk(list, f);

    free(list.buf);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Why is this? Why does the latter approach not work as expected?

The expected output should be something like:

```
LIST
ssss
TEST
xxxx
```

Where "ssss" is the size and "xxxx" is any random data (4 bytes).

I have seen approaches that instead passes structs as pointers to them (`&my_struct_var`) and accesses the members in a function by deferencing them as `my_struct_var->member`, but can I pass the struct as it is?

Comment: Are you sure your header file looks like the way you said? :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes. Why? It compiles for me with GCC at least.

Comment: @user966939: Because you should almost never define functions in header files.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths ah, you mean I should be prototyping? I was never too fond of that myself, but I see your point. Any ideas about the real issue?

Comment: @user966939: You will find yourself suddenly becoming very fond of it the first time you need to use one of those functions in more than one source file.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function with `out = func(in);` means that if the function modifies the contents of `in` those modifications will only be visible within the function. When the function returns the calling function will still have the same contents in the variable `in`. Doing a call by value could be described as the called function gets its own copy of the variable.

You have two options to solve your problem:

1) As you already suggested yourself, your function init_list_chunk could take a pointer to your structure. By then modifying the structure the pointer points to those modifications will be usable also for the calling function.

2) Instead of returning void your init_list_chunk could return the modified structure. Something like: `list = init_list_chunk(list, "TEST");` or even `list = init_list_chunk("TEST");` as there is no useful input information within list at the time of the function call.

Comment: Ah, I see! Good point on the second solution, hadn't thought about that.